# How to execute multiple actions for same event in richfaces a4j:support?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces, jsf-2.2

I need to execute two independent action method when an **onchange** event occurred on `rich:calendar` value is changed.

On below code snippets which is correct and performs well?

**Snippet :1**
Does this a valid EL?

```
<rich:calendar id="startDate" value="#{requestScopedBean.startDate}">
   <a4j:support ajaxSingle="true" event="onchanged"
                action="#{requestScopedBean.method1,requestScopedBean.method2}"
                reRender="field1,field2,field3">
 </a4j:support>
</rich:calendar>
```

**Snippet :2**

```
<rich:calendar id="startDate" value="#{requestScopedBean.startDate}">
   <a4j:support ajaxSingle="true" event="onchanged"
                action="#{requestScopedBean.method1}"
                reRender="field1,field2,field3">
   </a4j:support>
   <a4j:support ajaxSingle="true" event="onchanged"
                action="#{requestScopedBean.method2}"
                reRender="field1,field2,field3">
   </a4j:support>
</rich:calendar>
```

Please suggest me the correct option to bind two action method to an event in richfaces?

Comment: @DivagarHaldurai: Please find another aspect of this question via [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41457243/pagination-not-working-in-jsf-richdatascroller)

Comment: Why not combine the methods into one?